# NPM run dev command always fails at "grunt develop:quick" script

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

Using a cloned repository, I am trying to run npm run dev in order to develop locally. I have installed the grunt commands globally and my npm is recently updated. A possible problem I can see is that my node.js is at 5.10. However, if possible, I'd like to keep it there due to other team members having history with the repository not working on updated versions of node.js. The root of my repository is saved in the web folder and this is through Windows PowerShell(Admin).

```
PS C:\Users\<User>\Documents\GitHub\web> npm run dev

> web@12.5.6 dev C:\Users\<User>\Documents\GitHub\web
> grunt develop:quick

Running "develop:quick" (develop) task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "copy:modules" (copy) task
Copied 24 files

Running "base-sass-config" task
Interim sass config file [client\styles\core\__config.scss] created.

Running "glob-sass-components" task
Traversing: 
C:\Users\oalyousf\Documents\GitHub\web\client\src\components\pages
Traversing: 
C:\Users\oalyousf\Documents\GitHub\web\client\src\components\building-blocks
Interim components glob file [client\styles\core\__components.scss] created.

Running "sass:static" (sass) task
>> File to import not found or unreadable: ....srcomponentspages­min- 
consolestyles­min-console.scss
>> Parent style sheet: 
C:/Users/<User>/Documents/GitHub/web/client/styles/core/__components.scss
>>   Line 4  Column 1  client\styles\core\__components.scss
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! web@12.5.6 dev: `grunt develop:quick`
npm ERR! Exit status 6
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the web@12.5.6 dev script 'grunt develop:quick'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the web package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt develop:quick
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs web
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls web
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<User>\Documents\GitHub\web\npm-debug.log
PS C:\Users\<User>\Documents\GitHub\web>
```

Comment: Try updating nodejs and npm version

Comment: Already tried before, reverted back after that didn't solve it